# How to select rows that have more than one value in a list[datetime[µs]] column?

Tags: python, python-polars

I trying to learn the package Polars. I have a dataframe with datetime column.
So I imported the csv file
`df_order_dataset = pl.read_csv(file = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/Olist/Datasets/raw_datasets/olist_orders_dataset.csv', parse_dates=True)`

The column type (second column) was as shown in the image below.

[image]

Some rows have more than one value, like the last row in the image above.
I'm interested in the rows where the second column has more than one value, I thought of filtering by the list size but I can't get the list size of each row.

How can I do a filter based on the lines that have two or more values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this

```py
df.filter(
    pl.col("order_purchase_timestamp").arr.lengths() >= 2
)
```